# How to test Camel routes defined in the Java DSL when using another TestRunner?

Tags: testing, apache-camel, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to test my Camel routes using Cucumber, which requires me to use another TestRunner (Cucumber.class). In the tests I would like to mock certain endpoints.

I read that my test class should extend the CamelSpringTestSupport class. Extending the class requires me to implement the createApplicationContext() method. On the web I find many examples how to do that when you use xml to define your routes. One example is:

```
protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context.xml");
    }
```

However, how do you implement this method if you use the Java DSL?

Comment: In camel-test-spring there are a number of annotations you can use for some of the same functionality that you get from the camel test running. Look some more in the docs, examples etc.

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks for your reply. However, all the examples seem to either use CamelSpringRunner (which I cant use) or extend CamelSpringTestSupport (which I cant get to work and what this question is about). Is there a way to either get CamelSpringTestSupport work with Java DSL (answer to this question) or to use the stuff without the runner or testsupport class?

Comment: There are these annotations you can set on the classlevel such as: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-test-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/spring/MockEndpoints.java

Comment: @ClausIbsen For those who are searching for the MockEndpoints reference you give. 

The link is changed to: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-test/camel-test-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/spring/MockEndpoints.java